# Get a param sent in request by curl

Tags: php, symfony, curl

I have this curl :

```
curl -vvv "http://test/app_dev.php/transfer/file"  -F "file[test]"=@file.csv
```

In this route : `/transfer/file` I get the file and I need to get one more item :

```
$type = $request->request->get('type') == 'true' ? true : false;
```

How to modify `curl` in order to get `type` value in the php code. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -vvv 'http://test/app_dev.php/transfer/file?type=true'  -F 'file[test]'=@file.csv
```

cURL will accept get parameters as long as you enclose the URL between quotes

or you can use the -d option

```
-d 'type=true'
```

Comment: could you test with following: curl -d "@data.json" -X POST and in data.json place some test data, for example : {
  "key1":"value1",
  "key2":"value2"
} BTW, what error do you get?